# How can I include the EOLN in a conditional formatting

Tags: smartformat.net

I have the following as part of my text for SmartFormat:

```
When: {Event.StartDateTime:M} {Event.StartDateTime:t} - {Event.EndDateTime:t}.

{Event.ShowAddress:cond:Where: {Event.Address}|}

{Event.ShowRemote:cond:{Event.Zoom.Description}: {Event.Zoom.Url}|}

Again, thank you for stepping up to help. This is how we win.
```

I also tried:

```
When: {Event.StartDateTime:M} {Event.StartDateTime:t} - {Event.EndDateTime:t}.

{Event.ShowAddress:cond:Where: {Event.Address}
|}
{Event.ShowRemote:cond:{Event.Zoom.Description}: {Event.Zoom.Url}
|}
Again, thank you for stepping up to help. This is how we win.
```

It does great on the `cond` only showing the line if `ShowAddress` is true. But if `ShowAddress` is false, I get 2 blank lines. And I want the lines spread out, with a blank line between each, if both conditions are true.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If EOLN it meant to be the new line character, you can use it in the format string by using the **\n** text literal. Or, if you need carriage return and linefeed: **\r\n**.

Without a working code sample it's a bit difficult to give a precise answer. What I mean is to put both placeholders on 1 line, and add then \n literal in those cases where you need it:

```
{Event.ShowAddress:cond:Where: {Event.Address}\n|}{Event.ShowRemote:cond:{Event.Zoom.Description}: {Event.Zoom.Url}\n|}
```

Comment: Are you saying the property `Event.Address` in the example above needs the `\n` at the end of it and then give the entire `cond` no `EOLN` in the main text? If so, that's not great as I have to create an additional property just for this - which is not optimum. If I'm not understanding, please correct me. TIA

Comment: Also, it's a really useful library - thanks for creating it.

Comment: I added a code sample to better explain the usage of \n